# Using Twilio iOS SDK error on initialization

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

Im tyring to use the Twilio iOS SDK with Swift and when I attempt to initialise a TCDevice Object I get the following error
`Cannot find an initializer for type 'TCDevice' that accepts an argument list of type '(capabilityToken: NSString?, delegate: nil)'`

The code looks like this `self.device = TCDevice(capabilityToken: token, delegate: nil)`

and the token is this `var token = body as? NSString`

Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi Sam, please checkout my Answer and if possible post my needed information :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Pretty sure that the compiler is complaining about you trying to pass it an optional type for the capability token.  Try unwrapping the optional:

```
self.device = TCDevice(capabilityToken: token!, delegate: nil)
```

Also, check out these two blog posts I wrote on using the Twilio Client for iOS SDK with Swift:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/a-swift-adventure-building-basicphone-with-twilioclient.html
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/a-swift-adventure-building-basicphone-with-twilioclient-part-2.html

These posts were both written using Swift 1.1, so make sure you also reference the source in [Github](https://github.com/devinrader/SwiftPhone/releases/tag/v1.0) which has been updated to be compatible with Swift 2.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Those are really great and i have been using them but unfortunately some of the code doesn't work in the latest stable version of xCode and Swift

Comment: Ah, right.  I've updated the code in the Git repo so that it works in XCode 6.4.  https://github.com/devinrader/SwiftPhone/releases/tag/v1.0  I'm working on getting the code in the post updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Twillo, but the only to things I could imagine are these...

Please try this:

```
self.device = TCDevice(capabilityToken: token!, delegate: self)
```

To give you the right answer I need the following... please type in your Xcode just this:

```
self.device = TCDevice(
```

Than Xcode will autocomplete the initializer... Copy the Autocomplete and post it here... Than I could help you without guessing :-)